# Deep association in cakephp3 is not saving the Data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i have association like this `company ==> hasMany Cohorts` and `Cohorts ==> contains hasMany` with other 6 tables ex: `CohortTimeConfig`.

Now i am retrieving the default value from Cohorts table and that's fine like this.

```
$cohorts = $this->Companies->Cohorts
        ->find('all', [
            'conditions' => [
                'company_id IS NULL and status_id = 1'
            ],
            'contain' => [
                'CohortConfigs',
                'CohortPpmCategories',
                'CohortRanges',
                'CohortRoadClassConfig',
                'CohortTimeConfig',
                'CohortWeatherConfig'
            ],
            'order' => ['id' => 'ASC']
        ])
        ->toArray();
```

now what i am doing is changing the $cohorts like this

```
$company_id = $company->id;
array_walk($cohorts, function (&$cohort, $index) use ($company_id) {
    unset($cohort['id']);
    $cohort['company_id'] = $company_id;

    //cohort_time_config
    if(!empty($cohort['cohort_time_config'])){
        array_walk($cohort['cohort_time_config'], function (&$cohort_time_config, $key) {
            unset($cohort_time_config['id']);
            unset($cohort_time_config['cohort_id']);
        });
    }
});
```

At the end i am trying to save the all values with associations once like this

```
$allCohorts = $this->Companies->Cohorts->newEntity();
$allCohorts = $this->Companies->Cohorts->patchEntity($allCohorts, $cohorts);

debug(
    $this->Companies->Cohorts->save($allCohorts,[
        'atomic'=>true,
        'validate' => true,
        'associated' => [
            'CohortConfigs',
            'CohortPpmCategories',
            'CohortRanges',
            'CohortRoadClassConfig',
            'CohortTimeConfig',
            'CohortWeatherConfig'
        ]
    ])
);
```

i want to mentioned that my `//debug($allCohorts->errors());` is gives no error. That means all the rules check are ok. But Data is not getting saved.

can anybody can help me? and how can i debug it why it's not saving the data?

Comment: When posting code, please take the time to format in a readable manner, and make sure that it's syntactically correct (your second code block is missing a closing parenthese and semicolon) - thanks!

Comment: sorry for that. edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like many data retrieve and want to save many data but you use like saveing one data
Your Entity

```
$allCohorts = $this->Companies->Cohorts->newEntity();
$allCohorts = $this->Companies->Cohorts->patchEntity($allCohorts, $cohorts);
```

It should be Like

```
$allCohorts = $this->Companies->Cohorts->newEntities();
$allCohorts = $this->Companies->Cohorts->patchEntities($allCohorts, $cohorts);
```

Or you may also use

```
$allCohorts = $this->Companies->Cohorts->newEntities($allCohorts);
$this->Companies->Cohorts->saveMany($allCohorts);
```

For more see [Saving Multiple Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities)

Comment: Hi @tarikul05 I have tried with newEntities() and patchEntities() and also with saveMany(). but no luck

Comment: your tried ` 'associated'` array included ?? it should included

Comment: Yah i have included `associated` array. :(